# Best way to securely store google service account private key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-authentication, service-accounts

I'm developing an .NET MVC web app and using a google service account to create/delete calendar events on users personal calendars. I'm not sure what would be the best way to secure my google authentication key so that only my program has access to it. Currently it's just in the solution folder for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Best" is subjective. All I can tell you are options:

1. Put it in the Web.config as an App Setting, and then encrypt your `appSettings` configuration section. This is probably the safest route, if not the most convenient.
2. Put it in your code. It's not uncommon for developers to create a static `Settings` class that holds various bits of information the application needs. However, this means it will be plain text in the source. That's really only a problem if you plan to open-source your code or otherwise store it some place that's accessible to others (and that includes malicious others that shouldn't actually be able to access it). For example, I'd recommend only putting the source on a TFS or Git server internally, behind a firewall, rather than something on the Internet or public-facing. Once the code is compiled, you obviously won't have it in plain text anymore. However, if someone gains access to the compiled code, they could still decompile it and potentially find the string. To protect against that, you could use any number of obfuscation programs out there.

Comment: You're right. Best wasn't how I should have phrased it. Thanks for the advice.